# while loop in Jmeter runs without an end when the condition fails

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run a http request within while loop controller. I am running into an issue where the loop runs without end when there is a issue with the service that should change the status.

${__jexl3(${__jm__While Controller__idx} < 50 && "${Status}"!="Ready",)}

This is done with the intention that the while loop runs for 50 times and then ends. But, it doesnt seem to run 50 times. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition assumes that the code will exit from the loop when:

1. While Controller loops for 50 times
2. or `${Status}` becomes `${Ready}`

**whatever comes the first**

So the list of possible scenarios is:

- If `${Status}` is `Ready` - the While Controller won't execute at all
- While Controller will be executing until the `${Status}` becomes `Ready` but not more than 50 times

If you experience any problems:

- Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries
- Check `__jm__While Controller__idx` and `Status` variables values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)